# How to make a multi column Flutter DataTable widget span the full width?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a 2 column flutter DataTable and the lines don't span the screen width leaving lots of white space.  I found this issue

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12775

That recommended wrapping the DataTable in a SizedBox.expand widget but that does not work produces `RenderBox was not laid out:`

```
SizedBox.expand(
                    child: DataTable(columns:_columns, rows:_rows),
            ),
```

[image]

Full widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [Container(Text('My Text')),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: SizedBox.expand(
                        child: DataTable(columns:_columns, rows:_rows),
                ),
          ),
        ),
      ]))
    );
  }
```

Comment: what is the parent of your SizedBox.expand ?  could you add your build method

Comment: @diegoveloper it is a child of SingleChildScrollView, which is a child of a Container

Comment: @Eugene I've added the full widget code to the original post

Answer (score 34):

You can add the `crossAxisAlignment` for your `Column` to strech

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
```

Comment: This makes the column stretch but it doesn't take the DataTable widget to stretch with it.  It seems inherently limited in the DataTable itself.

Comment: @user1961 Works fine for me

Answer (score 20):

`SizedBox.expand` results in the `DataTable` taking an infinite height which the `SingleChildScrollView` won't like. Since you only want to span the width of the parent, you can use a `LayoutBuilder` to get the size of the parent you care about and then wrap the `DataTable` in a `ConstrainedBox`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text('My Text'),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.minWidth),
                  child: DataTable(columns: [], rows: []),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like charm!  I give you thumbs. :)

Comment: In my case, I had to change constraints.minWidth to constraints.maxWidth and remove the ScrollViews to do the trick

Answer (score 17):

This is an issue, incompleteness, in an otherwise beautiful Widget which is the DataTable,
I faced this issue in a production code, this solution worked on more than half of the lab devices:

```
ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand( 
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
        ),
child: DataTable( // columns and rows.),)
```

But you know what suprisingly worked on %100 of the devices ? this:

```
Row( // a dirty trick to make the DataTable fit width
      children: <Widget>[ 
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: DataTable(...) ...]//row children
```

Note: The Row has only one child Expanded which in turn enclose a SingleChildScrollView which in turn enclose the DataTable.

Note that this way you can`t use SingleChileScrollView with  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, in case you need it, but you don`t otherwise this question would be irrelevant to your use case.

In case someone of the Flutter team reads this, please enrich the DataTable Widget, it will make flutter competitive and powerful, flutter may eclipse androids own native API if done right.

Comment: The second one is super great, works with ScrollBar too. Just released my app without testing on tablets. get i was too excited. Now updates are on the way!

Comment: "otherwise this question would be irrelevant..." not necessarily. I need the horizontal scrolling to make the UI responsive, taking up the full width when the view area is wide and scrollable when it is narrow.

Answer (score 12):

Set your **datatable** in **Container** and make container's **width** as **double.infinity**

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: DataTable(
      columns: _columns,
      rows: _rows,
    ));
```

Answer (score 8):

For **DataTable** widget this code has worked for me regarding dataTable width as match parent to device-width,

**Code snippet:**

```
ConstrainedBox(
constraints: 
BoxConstraints.expand(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
),
child: 
DataTable(
    // inside dataTable widget you must have columns and rows.),)
```

and you can remove **space between columns** by using attribute like

```
 columnSpacing: 0,
```

**Note:**

using **ConstrainedBox** widget solves your issue,

```
constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
```

**Complete Code :**

**Note:**
In this sample code, I covered **sorting** and **editing** DataTable widget concepts.

*In Lib Folder you must have this class*

1. main.dart
2. DataTableDemo.dart
3. customer.dart

**main.dart class code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'DataTableDemo.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DataTableDemo(),
    );
  }
}
```

**DataTableDemo.dart class code**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'customer.dart';

class DataTableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DataTableDemo() : super();
  final String title = "Data Table";

  @override
  DataTableDemoState createState() => DataTableDemoState();
}

class DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  List<customer> users;
  List<customer> selectedUsers;
  bool sort;
  TextEditingController _controller;
  int iSortColumnIndex = 0;
  int iContact;

  @override
  void initState() {
    sort = false;
    selectedUsers = [];
    users = customer.getUsers();


    _controller = new TextEditingController();

    super.initState();
  }

  onSortColum(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
      if (ascending) {
        users.sort((a, b) => a.firstName.compareTo(b.firstName));
      } else {
        users.sort((a, b) => b.firstName.compareTo(a.firstName));
      }
    }
  }

  onSelectedRow(bool selected, customer user) async {
    setState(() {
      if (selected) {
        selectedUsers.add(user);
      } else {
        selectedUsers.remove(user);
      }
    });
  }

  deleteSelected() async {
    setState(() {
      if (selectedUsers.isNotEmpty) {
        List<customer> temp = [];
        temp.addAll(selectedUsers);
        for (customer user in temp) {
          users.remove(user);
          selectedUsers.remove(user);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  SingleChildScrollView dataBody() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
        child: DataTable(
          sortAscending: sort,
          sortColumnIndex: iSortColumnIndex,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
                label: Text("FIRST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is First Name",
                onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                  setState(() {
                    sort = !sort;
                  });
                  onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
                }),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("LAST NAME"),
              numeric: false,
              tooltip: "This is Last Name",
            ),
            DataColumn(label: Text("CONTACT NO"), numeric: false, tooltip: "This is Contact No")
          ],
          columnSpacing: 2,
          rows: users
              .map(
                (user) => DataRow(
                    selected: selectedUsers.contains(user),
                    onSelectChanged: (b) {
                      print("Onselect");
                      onSelectedRow(b, user);
                    },
                    cells: [
                      DataCell(
                        Text(user.firstName),
                        onTap: () {
                          print('Selected ${user.firstName}');
                        },
                      ),
                      DataCell(
                        Text(user.lastName),
                      ),
                      DataCell(Text("${user.iContactNo}"),
                          showEditIcon: true, onTap: () => showEditDialog(user))
                    ]),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
//          verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: dataBody(),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    child: Text('SELECTED ${selectedUsers.length}'),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    child: Text('DELETE SELECTED'),
                    onPressed: selectedUsers.isEmpty ? null : () => deleteSelected(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showEditDialog(customer user) {
    String sPreviousText = user.iContactNo.toString();
    String sCurrentText;
    _controller.text = sPreviousText;

    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Edit Contact No"),
          content: new TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter an Contact No'),
            onChanged: (input) {
              if (input.length > 0) {
                sCurrentText = input;
                iContact = int.parse(input);
              }
            },
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Save"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (sCurrentText != null && sCurrentText.length > 0) user.iContactNo = iContact;
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Cancel"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**customer.dart class code**

```
class customer {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int iContactNo;

  customer({this.firstName, this.lastName,this.iContactNo});

  static List<customer> getUsers() {
    return <customer>[
      customer(firstName: "Aaryan", lastName: "Shah",iContactNo: 123456897),
      customer(firstName: "Ben", lastName: "John",iContactNo: 78879546),
      customer(firstName: "Carrie", lastName: "Brown",iContactNo: 7895687),
      customer(firstName: "Deep", lastName: "Sen",iContactNo: 123564),
      customer(firstName: "Emily", lastName: "Jane", iContactNo: 5454698756),
    ];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

just wrap your DataTable with Sizedbox and give width to double.infinity.

```
SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: DataTable()
)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Simple Answer:**

Wrap your datatable with a `Container()` with `width: double.infinity()`.

```
    Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: DataTable( 
    
            ..
            .
```

**My Prefered Way**

You can use DataTable 2 Package at pub.dev 
https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2

This package will give you the `DataTable2()` widget which will expand to the available space by default. Also you get more options like `ColumnSize` etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Just wrap the data table with a container having fixed *width* defined and everything should work**.

Even when you need multiple tables in one screen this worked well for me as of flutter 2.2.3.

```
final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(child:Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            width: screenWidth, // <- important for full screen width
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 2, 0, 2),
            child: buildFirstTable() // returns a datatable
        ),
        Container(
            width: screenWidth, // <- this is important
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 2, 0, 2),
            child: buildSecondTable() // returns a datatable
        )
    ])
  ))
)
```

This also works for single table just wrap with container with desired width.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Card(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: DataTable(columns:_columns, rows:_rows),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: You might want to add some more details, code-only answer are not very useful

Comment: The code said it all.  I feel like there's no need to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: DataTable(
        columnSpacing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
        columns: const [
          DataColumn(label: Text('Product Name')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('Product Price')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('Product Type')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('Product Category')),
          DataColumn(label: Text('Product Description')),
        ],
        rows: productsList.map((product) {
          return DataRow(cells: [
            DataCell(Text(product.productName)),
            DataCell(Text(product.price)),
            DataCell(Text(product.typeOfProduct)),
            DataCell(Text(product.categoryOfProduct)),
            DataCell(Text(product.description)),
          ]);
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
```

**simple solution** is to use columnSpacing and **use this formula (width of screen / number of columns === width of the screen * (1/number of columns))** that is  `columnSpacing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2`  because **in my case column count is 5 so (screen width * (1/5 which is 0.2)).**

> hope this help Don't forget to wrap the **DataTable** with **SingleChildScrollView**

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?